# Update multiple nodes at once Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a chat app and using the following data structure:

[image]

Basically in `user_chats` I am keeping track of all the conversations a user is in, and what was the `last_message` in that conversation, so that later I can show this in a table view.

In the `messages` node I am storing all the messages of a given conversation by auto ID.

Now, when the user sends a message it should appear in the `messages` node of the given conversation, as well as in the `last_message` of the conversation for both users.

Before I was using dispatch groups and making individual calls to Firebase but that seemed to be very unreliable and inefficient.

**How could I updated all the values at the same time efficiently?**

**Extra:** Is this structure good for a 1-1 chat app?

**UPDATE WITH WORKING CODE:**

I have managed to update all values using the fan-out method.

Here is my code:

```
    NSDictionary *lastMessageDict = @{[self chatToUserID:userID] : @{@"last_message" : messageBody}};
    NSDictionary *singleMessageDict = @{@"body" : messageBody, @"time_stamp" : kTimeStamp, @"sender" : uID};
    NSString *autoID = [[self.databaseReference child:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"messages/%@/messages",[self chatToUserID:userID]]] childByAutoId].key;
    NSDictionary *messagesDict = @{[self chatToUserID:userID] : @{@"init" : facebookUserID , @"messages" : @{autoID : singleMessageDict}}};

    //Create fan out object
    NSMutableDictionary *fanOut = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [fanOut addEntriesFromDictionary:@{[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_chats/%@",uID] : lastMessageDict}];
    [fanOut addEntriesFromDictionary:@{[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_chats/%@",userID] : lastMessageDict}];
    [fanOut addEntriesFromDictionary:@{@"messages" : messagesDict}];

    [self.databaseReference updateChildValues:fanOut withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error,FIRDatabaseReference *reference){
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
        }

        else{
            NSLog(@"updated!");
        }
    }];
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Aside from that: yes, you can use a single multi-location update to send the updates in one go. See this blog post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html. If you're having trouble making it work, post the code that you have.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you so much! I got it working, the only thing I cannot figure out is how to give each message a unique ID. Could you help me with that? i updated my code!

Comment: Just generate a ref with a unique id with `let uniqueId = self.databaseReference.childByAutoId().key` and then use that key in the paths in your dictionary.

Comment: Thanks! Updated my code for others to see. Please post this as an answer so I can give you points!

Comment: Good to hear that you got it working. Can you post it as a self-answer? Unlike on other forums, self-answers are accepted and encouraged here on Stack Overflow. Posting the same code as an answer improves its chances of being found.

Comment: Okay! I am trying to set up the rules for this structure but for some reason regex is not working. Maybe you could help with that also?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877705/firebase-auth-uid-not-working-in-regex

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @Frank van Puffelen, I managed to get this working using the fan-out method. Here is my code:

```
NSDictionary *lastMessageDict = @{[self chatToUserID:userID] : @{@"last_message" : messageBody}};
NSDictionary *singleMessageDict = @{@"body" : messageBody, @"time_stamp" : kTimeStamp, @"sender" : uID};
NSString *autoID = [[self.databaseReference child:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"messages/%@/messages",[self chatToUserID:userID]]] childByAutoId].key;
NSDictionary *messagesDict = @{[self chatToUserID:userID] : @{@"init" : facebookUserID , @"messages" : @{autoID : singleMessageDict}}};

//Create fan out object
NSMutableDictionary *fanOut = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[fanOut addEntriesFromDictionary:@{[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_chats/%@",uID] : lastMessageDict}];
[fanOut addEntriesFromDictionary:@{[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_chats/%@",userID] : lastMessageDict}];
[fanOut addEntriesFromDictionary:@{@"messages" : messagesDict}];

[self.databaseReference updateChildValues:fanOut withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error,FIRDatabaseReference *reference){
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
    }

    else{
        NSLog(@"updated!");
    }
}];
```