# Firebase auth.uid not working in regex

Tags: regex, firebase

I want to allow read access to users only whose uid is somewhere in the node name.

I have the following rule in Firebase:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages" : {
      "$chat" :{
        ".read": "$chat.matches(/(auth.uid)/)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this does not seem to work. When `$chat` is `user45-user99` for example and the `auth.uid` is `user45-user99` or it is just simply `user45` it fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am assuming that `auth.uid` is being interpreted literally "auth.uid` and not a variable

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me as you can't use variables in Firebase RegEx because it treats them as strings.

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
$chats.contains(auth.uid)
```